# how to get icon programs in "Button.image or pictureBox.ImageLocation"

Tags: c#, windows, forms, visual-studio

i have problem, how to get icon program .exe
i have application i created and my application Process and kill but how to user know what program need to close it or start it.

The way is by showing the image of the program but how??

note: is there way to use Path?? example: "C:\Users\NameUser\Desktop\Chrome.exe" GetIcon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04KBQ.png)

im using visual studio windows forms C#

Thank You for hlep

the first answer the 2 code it doesn't work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLIHq.png)

Comment: There is no problem with the method proposed by Charles. Maybe you can provide some more details about the error code.

Comment: thank you very much. it's work after 1h tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
var icon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exeFilePath);
```

For a picture box you can use

```
pictureBox.Image = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(exeFilePath)?.ToBitmap();
```